How to factory reset a "New Rock HX420G" ATA
I have purchased a VoIP ATA with "New Rock" brand. Somehow I have misconfigured it and can no longer access its admin panel. This device has no reset button and no FXS ports (which some models use for resetting). Also no user manuals mention how to factory reset it without accessing the admin panel. Is there really no method to factory reset it without using the admin panel?
Product: HX4G VoIP ATA
Model: HS420G 
Brand:New Rock
things I have tested so far:

Try connecting using SSH/Telnet (Gives connection refused)
Open the device and try to find a jumper that resets it. (found one that just resets the device but does nothing more)


Sorry, for a device to be on topic here the vendor needs to offer optional, paid support, see the [help/on-topic]. For an on-topic business network you could try on [sf] or otherwise on [su].
